# Individual Field level boosting not working in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying a multimatch query and field level boosting is not working. the query I am using is

```
    "query": {
  "multi_match": {
     "query": "Primus Migration Issues",
     "fields": [
        "bkgdcontentList_exact^3"
        "procedure_exact^1",
     ],
     "type": "phrase"
  }
```

}

Inspite of bkgdcontentList_exact having the highest boost still I am getting result set which the query phrase is present in procedure_exact. 
I am not sure what I am missing. I am using ES 2.3.3.
The mapping for both field is same

Comment: You can use the explain functionality to look at how the score was computed - that query looks ok to me.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-request-explain.html

Comment: @paqash Thanks I got the issue now it was because of idf of the exact phrase over the document. Is there any way where we can have a mix functionality of type phrase and cross_field.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @paqash I have few record on which I do a exact search looking for the query phrase in bkgdcontentList_exact and procedure_exact. But when I do this because of type phrase, the doc appearing on top result has the phrase in procedure_exact, where as the doc with the query phrase in bkgdcontentList_exact should come as the top result.

Comment: Is it the exact same phrase in both fields? Are the mappings the same for both fields?

Comment: its not the same phrase but mapping is same for both